# I broke it! Custom post type archive gets redirected to home

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, archives

I've created a custom post type ('careers') in a plugin. I can create and view individual career posts just fine, but I can't view the archive page. It just redirects to the home page.

The following code creates the post type

```
function create_career_posttype() {
  $args = array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => __('Careers'),
      'singular_name' => __('Careers'),
      'all_items' => __('All Job Postings'),
      'add_new_item' => __('Add New Job Posting'),
      'edit_item' => __('Edit Job Posting'),
      'view_item' => __('View Job Posting')
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'careers'),
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'menu_position' => 6,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-universal-access'
    );
  register_post_type('careers', $args);
}
```

I've added a menu item for all the job postings by adding "all job postings" but it redirects to the home page for some reason. I also have an archive-careers.php defined. According to my (weak) understanding it should have a permalink of myurl/careers isn't that right?

I said I broke it in the subject because this used to work. Between that time and this I moved all the code from functions.php to a plugin with a great amount of pain ([working Custom Post Type and Widget code no longer works when moved from functions.php to plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/255077/working-custom-post-type-and-widget-code-no-longer-works-when-moved-from-functio)), and at one point I had some code in funtions to hide all category and archive pages which I have since removed and restarted the web server numerous times. That code looked like this:

```
/* Register template redirect action callback */
add_action('template_redirect', 'meks_remove_wp_archives');

/* Remove archives */
function meks_remove_wp_archives(){
  //If we are on category or tag or date or author archive
  if( is_category() || is_tag() || is_date() || is_author() ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404(); //set to 404 not found page
  }
}
```

Comment: To troubleshoot I would deactivate the plugin (you won't lose your content), reactivate it, then go to Settings > Permalinks and save without making changes. This will flush your permalinks and may solve the problem.

Comment: Two things I can think of: 1, what hook are you using for create_career_posttype()? It would need to most likely be init. 2, try going into your Wordpress Settings and going to permalinks. Just try hitting "Save Changes". It might refresh your permalink settings. This (for some reason) has worked for me before.

Comment: @Samyer all of the code is in the other question I linked to. It's ```    add_action( 'init', 'create_career_posttype');```

Comment: @WebElaine, yes I've tried that (several times)

Comment: How about deregistering the CPT altogether and re-registering it? If you changed anything about permalink structure along the way WP may not be using your latest code.

Comment: @WebElaine, isn't that what deactivating the plugin does?

Comment: No, deactivating actually won't completely deregister it. I've run into the same problem before, you have to programmatically unregister. http://www.mavengang.com/2016/07/12/unregister-post-type-using-unregister_post_type/ It sounds like this may actually delete posts so you may need to use a MySQL script to change the post types temporarily or back up just the wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables and re-import them after you unregister and re-register.

Comment: @WebElaine that didn't work either. I deactivated the plugin, added the delete_post_type method to functions, restarted the whole shebang, removed the function, then reactivated the plugin.

Comment: Hmm, I'm about out of ideas. One last thought: use http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php to see what header your desired URL is returning. Maybe there is a redirect (301 or 302) in place from another plugin or .htaccess? Only other thought, is it possible that you have some other taxonomy called "careers" (like a Page) that might be conflicting and confusing WP as to which to display?

Comment: @marcp I know this is a couple years old but I am having the same problem. Any luck figuring this out and would you have any clue what fixed it still?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to the rewrite rules not being updated. You need to run `flush_rewrite_rules()` or visit the Permalinks page in the WP-Admin and save it to flush the rewrite rules. If you use the function call in your plugin, be sure not to leave it in such that it gets run every time, it's not friendly that way.